# Как изменить background блока если ему задан бордер через linear-gradient

Tags: css

есть блок с заданным для него бордером через лайнер градиент, мне нужно сделать его прозрачным, если ввести background: transparent то border вообще пропадает через rgba тоже не работает

```
.getmore_item-border{
    border: double 3px transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#Ffffff,#ffffff), radial-gradient(circle at top left, #EB177E,#893EF9);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}
```

Comment: Из вашего вопроса вообще ничего непонятно, чего вы добиваетесь? Что хотите сделать прозрачным. Почему не используете  'opacity: 0'  если нужно опрозрачить весь блок. Уточните.

Answer (score -1):

Из вашей текущей реализации - никак. Рекомендую воспользоваться SVG.
Подробный ответ уже давали [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496204/border-gradient-with-border-radius)